# how to use cURL on specific route

Tags: curl, ipv6, route, traceroute

I have 2 ISPs on multi-homing and am trying to use `curl http://v6.ipv6-test.com/api/myip.php` to retrieve my current IPv6 address and store it on a log.

But due to having 2 ISPs, I need to do it for each of them.

`ip -6 route show` shows me that both prefixes are routable. Is there any way to force curl (or any other HTTP client that will print the output to stdout) to use a specific route, so that I can run it for both?

Here are my routes

```
$ ip -6 route show
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2804:xxxx:xxxx:585b::/64 dev eno1 proto ra metric 202 mtu 1500 pref medium
2804:yyyy:yyyy:d77f::/64 dev eno1 proto ra metric 202 mtu 1500 pref medium
fdfa::/64 dev eno1 proto ra metric 202 mtu 1500 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eno1 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
default via fe80::a236:9fff:feaa:4b68 dev eno1 proto ra metric 202 mtu 1500 pref medium
```

Comment: nvm, I just parsed `ip -6 route show`'s output and retrieved global prefixes from it, tnx :)

Comment: Can you add a schematic including your system, the two ISP and the router. Is the router correctly configured for multi-homing to the two ISPs itself? Or is there an other router too? That's to be sure the current answer can be applied (with an important change, the quote is actually: Perform an operation using a specified interface. You can  enter interface  name, **IP address or host name**. An example could look like: ... )

Answer (score 1):

curl man page:

```
--interface <name>
    Perform an operation using a specified interface.
```

Depending on your precise routing table (you could add it to the question), you could also play around with parameters like route metrics, but that would affect all network traffic, not only curl, and not only HTTP.

Comment: ALAIK it only works on the router and I need to use the network or pppoe interface, it doesn't work on routes. What should I use on it on devices on the LAN? I updated adding my routes.

Comment: I only see one interface in the routes. Whatever became of multi-homing?

Comment: 2804:xxxx:xxxx:585b::/64 is ISP1, 2804:yyyy:yyyy:d77f::/64 is ISP2.

Comment: So the Linux system where you run the test has only one interface. Your question is rather misleading, and my answer doesn't apply.

Comment: ... please, it's not. I has and always had 1 interface. I can't use curl --interface or ping -I or traceroute -i. It has 2 routes and I'm trying to find a way to set which *route* I wanna use. I always asked that. Nothing related to interfaces.

Comment: Remove one route. To avoid impacting other processes, do this in a network namespace.

Comment: Remove one, run curl, then add it back? How could I do it, and without knowing the prefix?

Comment: I believe you just do `ip r del ENTIRE_LINE`, then  `ip r add ENTIRE_LINE`, where ENTIRE_LINE is the relevant line from the the `ip -6 r` output.

Comment: To do that I need to know the line. The whole idea is to find out my address, log it and know over time when it was changed. I'd have to hope that routes order won't change... I'm considering to just read `ip route show` output, substring the prefixes from it and just use them instead of the whole address.

Comment: --interface shouldn't be used with an interface but an address.